# Enumeration TQDM Progress Bar Not Working

Tags: python, enumerate, tqdm

I have a progress bar inside an enumerate loop, but it never goes to 100%. Instead, it will stop at something like 45/50 or 995/1000. It appears to not be running the command for every enumeration, but I don't know how that's possible. The relevant code is below.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
data = []
numTweets = 50
pbar = tqdm(total=numTweets,
            desc='Collecting Tweets')
for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('COVID Vaccine since:2021-01-01 until:2021-05-31').get_items()):
    pbar.update(n=1)
    if i > numTweets:
        break
    data.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.content])
```

Comment: Have you tried `enumerate(tqdm(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('COVID Vaccine since:2021-01-01 until:2021-05-31').get_items()))` and removing pbar altogether?